# Protractor -- TimeoutError Before Any Tests Begin

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I'm trying to run a protractor suite for a web application. When I first run the config file, the automated browser goes to a blank white page and waits for ten seconds.

After waiting, the console flashes with an error. That error repeats itself for every test

```
<Should do _____>
TimeoutError: waiting for page to load for 10000ms
Wait timed out after 10005ms
<list of many paths tracking back to a promise.js file>
```

Meanwhile, on the browser, all the tests are being performed normally. The automation still works, the console doesn't show that the automation works.

The same thing happens in both Firefox and Chrome. I've tried running a different test file out of the Config and I'm met with the same error. But when I run a blank test file. The error doesn't occur.

Edit: I tried to increase the time of timeout. The page always loads directly after the timeout is done. Also, when I change one of my tests to a blank test, (or a test that just gets the website) it works perfectly.

Comment: You may want to increase the timeout value in the *protractor.conf.js*. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md

Answer (score 0):

There was a `browser.refresh()` outside an it statement deep in one of my methods. I removed the refresh statement and the test suite resumed working perfectly.

Note: This `browser.refresh()` didn't show up in the timeout message I had to find it by hand.